# Flutter stuck on Splash Screen with Icon Showing, not going forward

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, splash-screen, flutter-dependencies

I am using command line to build the apk. It builds and installs in my android device, but stuck on Splash Screen with a Icon. What problem should it be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you using the splashscreen package? What does your code looks like? Please provide more informations so we can help better.

Comment: If there are any API call is in splash screen, make sure you have added internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>